# Illustrator automatically switches from color to stroke

Tags: adobe-illustrator

This is my brush toolbar when I'm trying to draw a line:
[image]

However, **immediately** after I start drawing it changes to this:
[image]

Note that for some reason the stroke has now been added, I have no idea why. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Does it happens when you use the brush on the empty workspace? Or did you used the brush on something else?

Comment: On an empty workspace, newly created.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this post](http://topbrushes.com/questions/photoshop-cs/cant-use-paintbrush-in-illustrator-cs/) that could help out.
If you scroll down a bit 2 really helpfull answers are being shown (I don't want to act like they are mine):
sarah posted:

> i had that problem on illustrator cs4 (circle with a slash through it when i chose paint tool) and found that the brushes were not loaded. go to the right hand brushes icon on your toolbar and pop it out. then click the down arrow and scroll down to load calligraphic brushes. then you can browse for a brush style, all of a sudden you are able to find all your colors and paint on your image.
>   hope this is helpful

GizmoJones posted:

> Go to the menu and select Window –> Brushes to open the little “Brushes” window. If it’s empty, you haven’t chosen a calligraphic style for your brush. Click on the arrow in the corner of the “Brushes” box, and select “Open brush library.” Pick a style, which will show up as a tab in the box, and your brush will work.

Hopefully this helps you to use the brush-tool again, cheers!

Comment: No, sorry - the brushes are all loaded.